# Facebook fanbox widget fbxml problem at Friseur in München

Tags: facebook, fbml, xfbml

Sometimes iv'e got the problem that no facebook fanbox is load on my companies website [Friseursalon München](http://www.friseure-in-muenchen.de/). Can't find a problem in the fbxml code:

```
<fb:fan profile_id="395375265611" connections="10" width="334" height="285" css="http://www.x-hair.de/cms/css/facebook.css"></fb:fan>
```

Any suggestions? Anybody else with the same issue?

Thanks,
Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any mistakes in the facebook fan code.

You should add the facebook xmlns string at the top of your page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This solved some problems for me in Internet Explorer.

You could try to load the newest version of the js SDK.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
</script>
```